# Pipe under bathroom sink has small hole

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, hole

[image: Faucet]

One of the pipe under my bathroom sink has small hole and it sprays water as soon as i start/open faucet. Red circle in above photo shows where the hole is. Which pipe is that? Where can i find that pipe and how easy is to replace it? Is there any quick fix to repair it instead of replace it?

There is shelter-in-place in city in which I live. I don't want to hire plumber to fix this if this is easy to fix. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That's a proprietary crossover line that would've come with your faucet. Exact parts may not be easy to find. However, you could probably fix that with a two-way nipple and some standard hose clamps. You'd just cut the line at the leak point, insert the nipple into each stub, and clamp it snug.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know what size of two-way nipple  can i use? I dont know size of that pipe.

Comment: Since you can't use the sink/faucet because of the leak, Just cut it at the leak and look at the inside diameter of the hose.  Most likely it's a 3/8 " ID hose.

Comment: I would guess 3/8” or 1/4” a trip to the store cost more than getting a couple of sizes 2 hose clamps also 1 for each side , I have used zip ties in a pinch but don’t recommend them to hold tubing on the barbs.

Comment: Put the hose clamps on each stub before inserting the nipple. :-)+